# Converting string to chemical formula

Tags: formula

convert a string "C11H15NO3" into chemical formula in Nuxt Js

```
var string = 'C11H15NO3',
result = string
    .split(/(\d+)/)
    .map((s, i) => i % 2 ? `<sub>${s}</sub>` : s)
    .join('');

console.log(result)
```

Out Put :
C<sub>11</sub>H<sub>15</sub>NO<sub>3</sub>

But I need out put like   : C11H15NO3
[likethis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwUOY.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is just the output of `console.log()` because it is still just a string. If you write to the document it will load into the DOM and render as html.

```js
var string = 'C11H15NO3',
  result = string
  .split(/(\d+)/)
  .map((s, i) => i % 2 ? `<sub>${s}</sub>` : s)
  .join('');

console.log(result)
document.write(result)
```